# Swift Key Path causes EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in NSSortDescriptor

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift4

I am trying to use an `NSSortDescriptor` so sort a list of structs using a Key Path in Swift 4. But the initialization of the `NSSortDescriptor` crashes with an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` in `NSSortDescriptor`

```
struct Foo {
    let bar : Int
    let baz : String
}

let x = [Foo(bar: 1, baz: "Hello"),
         Foo(bar: 2, baz: "World")]

let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Foo.baz, ascending: true)
```

The relevant stack trace looks like this.

```
#0  0x00000001007f97a0 in specialized _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) ()
#1  0x0000000100ec5a12 in specialized static _KVOKeyPathBridgeMachinery._bridgeKeyPath(_:) ()
#2  0x0000000100e32142 in NSSortDescriptor.init<A, B>(keyPath:ascending:) ()
```

This makes me think that NSSortDescriptor does not work with non-KVO objects, however neither the compiler gives me a warning, nor does the documentation of NSSortDescriptor mention that the key path needs to be for an object that is exposed to the Objective-C runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the keypath-based sort descriptor requires a property which
is exposed to the Objective-C runtime, and that requires a `class`:

```
class Foo {
    let bar : Int = 0
    @objc let baz : String = ""
}
```

The unhelpful diagnostics is already traced as [SR-5115
KeyPath-based KVO: No diagnostic for inaccessible KVO KeyPaths](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5115).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So the Objective-C runtime is needed for NSSortDescriptor? I kind of expected that, but still kind of a bummer. I really would have liked to use it for structs.

Comment: @ThomasBartelmess: Yes. Also you can apply it to `NSArray` only, so its use for native Swift types is very limited.

Answer (score 1):

For sorting custom class array using NSSortDescriptors in swift 4, you need to declare class as below.

```
@objcMembers class Model:NSObject {

        var title:String
        var num:Int
        init(title:String,num:Int) {
            self.title = title
            self.num = num
        }

    }
```